# Failing google addon trigger, but the addon doesn't know it is installed

Tags: google-sheets

So this appears to have happened because some version of this google sheet was once owned on a domain with fewer addon restrictions than mine. They installed 6 or 7 addons, including one that has an onEdit trigger.

These addons cannot be installed on my work domain, so they cannot be seen by the "manage addons" feature, but they all show up in the addons dropdown or the "document addons" sidebar.

One of them causes issues for one user whenever she modifies a row (it creates a prompt to install the addon from an onedit trigger) that I cannot access from the script trigger interface, either in executions or by writing a script to run through the existing triggers (GAS doesn't know about it).

Any idea how to purge these? Making a copy still shows those addons in the addons dropdown.

Comment: Does this happen on other sheets or just this specific one? What about newly created sheets?

Comment: newly created sheets do not show these addons. a fresh copy of the sheet also shows the addons.